# Implementing sqlite3_busy_timeout() in an iOS app

Tags: ios, sqlite

I have a iOS app that uses Sqlite3 as the database.
The app is multithreading.

I want to make sure the app doesn't get SQlite data locks from one thread to another. I think sqlite3_busy_timeout() might be the answer.

My question is where do I put sqlite3_busy_timeout()? I open the connection to sqlite in the appdelegate. Should I put the sqlite3_busy_timeout() right after I open the sqlite connection, or do I need to put in every time I execute data call.

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not use transactions instead? this will ensure table inserts are done atomically.

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

```
 INSERT INTO "t1" VALUES(1, 'This is sample data', 3, NULL);

 INSERT INTO "t1" VALUES(2, 'More sample data', 6, NULL);

 INSERT INTO "t1" VALUES(3, 'And a little more', 9, NULL);

 COMMIT;
```

Comment: Transactions are good, but have nothing to do with the OP's issue, which is how to handle SQLITE_BUSY errors that result when trying to run a query/statement while another thread is holding the database lock.

Answer (score 3):

This is from http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/busy_timeout.html:

"There can only be a single busy handler for a particular database connection any(at) any given moment. If another busy handler was defined (using sqlite3_busy_handler()) prior to calling this routine, that other busy handler is cleared. "

So if you're executing data calls in a multiple threads the above requirement of a 'single busy handler' would be violated.

I would recommend putting it in the app delegate.

hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, yes it does. One more question, if a database is locked will sqlite3 just continue to try to excute the statement for as long as defined without me doing anything