# SQLite The database file is locked during Insert/Delete

Tags: visual-c++, sqlite

I am using a C++ shell extension DLL which used to read, write data into the SQLite database tables. There another  application ( exe) which  used to access all the tables.

Sometimes,  my dll displaying an  exception "The database file is locked" when I try to Delete/Insert/Update to the SQLite Database tables. This is  because the other application was accessing the tables at this time.

Is there any way to resolve this issue from my DLL?  Can I use the solution as mentioned in the link : "*http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455290/implementing-sqlite3-busy-timeout-in-an-ios-app*"

In the current code, I am using  **CppSQLite3.cpp** method **execQuery**(const char* szSQL)  to execute the SQL query.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should know that SQLite does a Database level locking. When you start a transaction and the other application tries to write something to the same database, then you get `Database is locked` and SQLite automatically tries executing that same query after `sqlite3_busy_timeout` interval.

So the trick is to make sure you keep your transactions are as short as possible i.e 
1. Do a begin transaction 
2. Update/Delete/Insert 
3. Commit

and not have anything else between these 3 steps.
And also increase your `sqlite3_busy_timeout` interval to suite your application depending on how large your transactions are.

You can try `WAL` mode, where reading and writing to SQLite can be done at the same time. But it comes with its own set of disadvantages. You can refer SQLite [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/draft/wal.html).

Comment: Thanks@DJK. thanks omggs. Our exe and DLL applications are accessing the same database tables. Exe accessing table1,table2 and table3. DLL is accessing table1 and table2. The issue is Exe- table3 insert takes longer time. This causing Database file locked scenario. I think the work around is move the table3 to another database. I think this will resolve our issue

Comment: @JChan: You are welcome! Sure, you can move the table to another database or increase the busy time which ever suits your application!

Answer (score 0):

SQLite has some restrictions regarding multiple users and multiple transactions. That means you can't read/write on a resource from different transactions. The database will be locked when the database is being updated.

Here are some links that might help you

http://sqlite.org/c3ref/busy_timeout.html

http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/busy_handler.html

Good Luck